# Meaning of mysql-ctl cli

Tags: mysql, sql

I am still learning the majority of SQL commands out there so please excuse me for asking a noob question.

When I am using MySQL online, in order to begin the actual 'coding/programming' in SQL I need to use the following command:

mysql-ctl cli

I understand that 'cli' refers to the command line interface, i.e. the tool through which to access the MySQL programme but what does the 'ctl' refer to? What is actually happening with this entire command in the background - why does it need to be run on an IDE at all instead of just starting to code in SQL language?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/SQL/comments/eq4ghr/meaning_of_ctl_on_mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Well usually you need just run
mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name
but some environments have additional utilities to control mysql server which are made looking similar to oracle crsctl or srvctl you may find in RAC
ctl means control
So mysql-ctl cli - starts command line interface
mysql-ctl start - starts mysql server
mysql-ctl stop  - stops  mysql server
there is nothing extraordinary

Comment: "some environments"??   Please add, at least, 1 of them.

Comment: I am trying to follow here - when the `mysql-ctl` code is run, in essence you are connecting and requesting to speak to the server on which MySQL is installed? Thereafter, with `cli` you are requesting the server to open the command line interface (which is basically a terminal or command prompt) through which to specify the SQL commands?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).